# How do i print an array out to the console?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, array-algorithms

I'm currently working to make a 2D grid which the user can select the start destination, end destination and obstacles in between. I would like to print the array (as shown above) to the console to help users visualise the the array they are traversing. I'm using Visual Studio and working in c++. Further to this, is there a function for the user to change particular parts of the array to 0's to create "obstacles"?

```
        { { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } },
          { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } },
          { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } },
          { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } },
          { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } },
          { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } },
          { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } },
          { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } },
          { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } } }
    };
```

Comment: You print any array by printing each element. This can be done by a simple function. Use the `<<` operator to output each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change specific parts of an array you can access it's values like this:

```
arr[4][5] = 5; // Returns the sixth element in the fifth row and changes it to 5
```

To print you would right something like this assuming you are working with std::vector (if not substitute arr.size() with a literal or your own variable).

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].size(); j++){
        std::cout << arr[i][j] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```